# Git shortlog does not show output in Jenkins shell

Tags: git, jenkins, terminal, command-line-interface, git-log

Facing some wired issue while working with Jenkins,

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x

#initialize environment
export PATH="$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8

cd ~/autobuild/projects/MyAPP
git checkout dev
git reset head --hard
git pull

git shortlog

git log
```

When i run this above script from Jenkins job, it shows git log output fine, but nothing for `git shortlog`. Whats the issue? MyApp has hundreds of commits.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally I was able to find the reason, `git shortlog` works fine when you directly use from terminal because,

```
git help shortlog
```

Shows,

> If no revisions are passed on the command line and either standard
>   input is not a terminal or there is no
>          current branch, git shortlog will output a summary of the log read from standard input, without reference to
>          the current repository.

So you must provide the reference explicitly while working with shell scripts,

```
git shortlog HEAD
```

Will work fine in that case.

Comment: Thanks for this. git manages to astonish once more :-)